# Como incorporo um vídeo do youtube no site começando do meio?

Tags: html, html5, html5-video

Quero incorporar um vídeo no meu site, mas, ao invés do vídeo começar do inicio, quero que ele comece só nos 15 segundos. Tem como fazer isso por meio do HTML?

Comment: Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Mais detalhes podem ser vistos no [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70) e em [Onde errei ao formular a pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/70)

Comment: Veja [Incorporar um player de vídeo do YouTube em seu website com <iframe>](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) e [Iniciando com a API de dados do YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Quando você abre um vídeo no Youtube, ele mesmo te dá a opção de incorporar, gerando o código pra você copiar e colar. Você ainda pode escolher a posição do vídeo.

Por exemplo, o link https://youtu.be/3F3hkXk1Hy4?t=2 inicia um vídeo em 2 segundos.
Ou você pode gerar um código de incorporação como este:

```
<!-- as linhas foram quebradas para ilustrar -->
<iframe 
  width="560" 
  height="315" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3F3hkXk1Hy4?controls=0&amp;start=2" 
  title="YouTube video player" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="
    accelerometer; 
    autoplay; 
    clipboard-write; 
    encrypted-media; 
    gyroscope; 
    picture-in-picture
  " 
  allowfullscreen 
></iframe>
```

Note que o parâmetro de tempo mudou de `t=2` para `start=2`. Existem muito mais parâmetros e valores que você pode usar, como o tempo em linguagem amigável: `#t=3m42s`.

Além dos parâmetros da URL, também tem os atributos do  que você está incorporando, [aqui você pode checar uma lista de alguns](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=pt-br). Mas existem mais do que o Google mostra, pois alguns caíram em desuso. Antigamente, por exemplo, se usava `<embed>` ao invés de `<iframe>`. Acontece que o `<embed>` conta como visualização cada vez que reproduz um vídeo. E dava pra *codar* e fazer milhares de views. Ainda deve dar, mas pro algorítimo não vale nada.

Comment: Valeu aí pelo deslike quem deu. Dou a resposta bem formatada e redigida e é esse o incentivo que alguns dão nessa comunidade.

Comment: Formatação não faz com que o assunto entre no escopo do site. Negativo também serve para desincentivar isso (e eu diria que voto **quando usado certo** é uma das melhores ferramentas do site). Me assusta é positivo errado. Positivo errado dá 10 pontos para a pessoa e incentiva o erro. Negativo certo tira só dois pontos, e ajuda definir a forma do site. Veja o número de usuários ativos na rede (são muitos). Se uma resposta é realmente boa, com negativos ou não no fim ela acaba positiva. Se não ocorrer, pode ser que a resposta não esteja tão boa ou adequada quanto pensa. https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @Bacco e cadê o erro? Chego a desconfiar de você tentando passar pano pra serial downvote.

Comment: São 4 negativos de **pessoas diferentes**, numa postagem recente que teve pergunta bem negativada também. Nada de anormal, e nada de "serial". Bom, não vou me estender, como já disse antes, se tiver algo a discutir, faça nos lugares apropriados (até porque, após melhor análise, notei você já teve outras discussões de down no passado usando campo de comentários) - Se não quer negativo, melhor usar uma plataforma sem sistema de avaliação. Numa plataforma em que pessoas tem direito a voto, dificil questionar (exceto em quebra de regras).

Comment: Agora, que fique claro: voto serial, por antipatia ou vingança realmente não é permitido, e como teve queixa, é sempre analisado. De qualquer forma se um dia tiver um padrão em série de natureza pessoal de fato (que claramente não é o caso aqui), ou votos de vingança, providências são tomadas e votos corrigidos - mas isso tudo já está mais do que descrito no site Meta, que indiquei. De qualquer forma, já estou me estendendo demais no espaço que não é pra isso. Se tiver algo a estender o assunto, faça no Meta ou no form de contato do rodapé. O campo de comentários não é pra discussão.

Comment: Cara valeu pela resposta, infelizmente eu n posso votar na minha própria pergunta por que n tenho reputação, mas a sua resposta foi de grande ajuda, exatamente o que eu queria.

Comment: @NoobDev você poderá dar voto positivo com mais alguns pontos e pode marcar a resposta dele como aceita. Seus pontos ainda não dão positivo, mas o aceito já vale 15 pontos pro autor da resposta. E qualquer outro dos muitos usuários que acharem que a resposta é adequada pro site e boa que tenha um minimo de pontos pode votar positivo ou negativo nele conforme entenda a utilidade para o objetivo do site.

Comment: E o sistema dos votos também acho esquisito, todas as perguntas que faço ficam fechadas, é complicado fazer uma pergunta 'adequada', como vê essa teve 5 votos negativos sabe-se lá por que.

Comment: @NoobDev vou colar uns links nela, participei do fechamento mas esqueci de postar. O problema dessa aqui é que apesar do "cenário" ser dentro de um código, não é um problema de desenvolvimento em si, e sim uma peculiaridade da documentação do Youtube (é coisa de mera consulta simples da documentação) - perguntas de suporte são feitas no site [su], que tentamos ter em portugues pra esses casos, mas a empresa não quis no momento. Ainda, teve o problema de nem colocar o trecho de código relevante pra dar contexto, um [mcve] sempre ajuda.

Comment: @NoobDev pronto, colei os links lá, espero que ajude nas próximas. E outra coisa, tem que lembrar que down e up é mera classificação de conteudo (como explicado no [tour]). Não é like ou dislike igual rede social, e sim critério técnico. Ou seja, mesmo que tenha negativos, não significa que você não é bem vindo, e sim que precisa melhorar elaboração ou verificar melhor o assunto da pergunta nas próximas (inclusive, dependendo da pergunta, se [edit] ela pode ser reaberta - não é só moderação que decide o conteudo do site, usuários normais votam por fechamento e aberturas também).